# Solving this trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I want to solve this equation

$$
\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x^2-x+1)=\pi/2
$$

I write this: for all $x\in [-1,1]$

$\arcsin(x^2-x+1)=\pi/2-\arccos(x)$ then $x^2-x+1=\sin(\pi/2-\arccos(x))=\cos(\arccos(x))=x$

$x^2-x+1=x\Rightarrow x^2-2x+1=0\Rightarrow (x-1)^2=0\Rightarrow x=1 $

Is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is *almost* correct.

I say almost because:

1. $\arcsin$ map is only defined on $[-1,1]$. Hence you have to restrict to $x \in [0,1]$ in order to have $x^2-x+1 \in [0,1]$.
2. You proceeded by implication. You should validate that $x=1$ is indeed a solution of the equation.

Apart from that your computations are correct.

Comment: I do the domain of $arcsin(x^2-x+1)$ is [0,1] , is it sufficient ?

Comment: No, this map is defined on $[-1,1]$. Why do you want to change this interval?

Comment: $x\in[-1,1]\implies x^2-x+1\in[-1,1]$ is too constraining. It only needs to hold for the solution(s) found.

Comment: I don't know how to prove that $x^2-x+1\in [-1,1]$ by supposing that $x\in [-1,1]$ how to ?

Comment: Just study the map $x \mapsto x^2 -x +1$. Taking the derivative if required.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-x+1, f'(x)=2x-1$ , $f'(x)=0$ means that $x=\frac12$, f(-1)=3 and f(1)=1 so how to do ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net are you here please ?

Comment: Indeed I was wrong. And $x$ has to belong to $[0,1]$ in order for $\arcsin(x^-x+1)$ to be define. I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\arccos(t)+\arcsin(t)=\dfrac\pi2$, implying
$$\arccos(x)=\frac\pi2-\arcsin(x^2-x+1)=\arccos(x^2-x+1)$$

and the arc cosine function, from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,\pi]$, is invertible so that this strictly equivalent to

$$x=x^2-x+1,x\in[-1,1]$$

which has the double root $x=1$.

Comment: Please how to prove that $x^2-x+1\in [-1,1]$ when $x\in [-1,1]$

Comment: @lindaOiladali: this is useless.

Comment: to have that arcsin(x^2-x+1) is well defined

Comment: @lindaOiladali: for the last time, this is useless. It is automatically fulfilled by a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes true indeed, in fact doubly true ( double root) at $ x=1$

Compare terms of two equations with identity

$$ \arccos(x)+\arcsin(x^2-x+1)=\pi/2 $$

$$ \arccos(x)+\arcsin(x)=\pi/2 $$

so we must have

$$ x^2-x+1 = x,\, x^2-2x+1 = 0,\,(x-1)^2=0,\,x= (1,1)$$

Solution can be verified by their graphs at  $(x=1)$ their average value is $y = \pi/4$ at $ x=1$ has a tangent point:

$$ \dfrac{\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x^2-x+1)}{2}=\pi/4 $$

[image]

It can be seen that $\arccos(x) $  has domain $(-1,1).$

However,  $\arcsin(x^2-x+1)$ and *hence* the sum $\arccos(x) + \arcsin(x^2-x+1)$ must have a restricted domain $(0,1)$.

When $x<0,\,\arcsin(x^2-x+1)$ is imaginary !

Comment: how to prove that if $x\in[-1,1]$ then $x^2-x+1\in[-1,1]$ please

Comment: Good question. That is why I indicated in the graph that $ \arcsin (x^2-x+1) $ forces the domain to be $ (0,1)$ whereas $ \arccos (x)$ has domain $(-1,1)$ all the way. So please note $( x^2-x+1) $ does NOT have that full domain.

Comment: so I must say fo all $x\in [0,1]$ right?

Comment: That is correct.